# Symmetrical brown dots on camellia leaves

Tags: identification, diseases, pest-control, insects, camellia

Help please. I’m located in the Pacific Northwest USA. I just noticed that much of the new growth on my (old) established camellia shrub has these odd brownish dots. Only 2-4 dots per leaf, all located on the underside and near the stem base. The dots are smaller on smaller leaves.

[image: green camellia leaves, with 2-4 small, brown dots on the underside of each leaf]

Dots are only visible on the underside of leaves, and some dots have a small bit of moisture, too. Saw an ant inspecting one, maybe eating the moisture?

Is it some kind of insect egg? A disease? Baffled that I can’t find it online. Shrub is several decades old, and was overgrown and pruned back before I moved in last fall. Any tips appreciated.